# My website design gets messed up when zoomed out, how do i fix this?

Tags: html, css, positioning, center

I've been messing with a couple of my webpages since they get completely screwed up when the webpage is zoomed out or zoomed in. I have tried `<center>` and `<div align:"center">` to center the webpage but it isnt seeming to work. The web pages that are causing grief are:

http://officialnewvintage.com/photos.html

http://officialnewvintage.com/joel.html

any ideas?

Comment: You need to put a `<div class="wrap"></div>` as `<center>` tag and `align` attribute of `div` are now invalid. :)

Comment: `<div align:"center">` was never a valid HTML, you might be looking for something like `<div style="align: center;">` or the now-obsolete `<div align="center">`

Comment: yes i meant `<div align="center">` and ill try the other one

Comment: @user1594170: the former will not work, it's not a valid CSS. The valid style declaration is `<div style="text-align: center;">`, which more clearly shows why it does not work, text-align are meant for text/inline elements. What do you want to happen when it's resized? There are two techniques that I generally use, one is to reflow the images so they always fill the whole width of the screen, the other is to squeeze the width and keep having 3-columns.

Comment: Buddy, there are a lot of issues in your markup. Need to fix it before it is valid and if it needs to work based on our comments.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap up the contents with a wrapper class, because `<center>` tag and `align` attribute of `div` are now invalid. :). For your issue, I suggest you to put a wrapper class like this, after the `body`.

```
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
    ...
    ...
    </div>
</body>
```

And in the CSS, please give a fixed width.

```
.wrap {width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;}
```

The width of `960px` is best for all the browsers as, it is by default used by `1024px` and `1280px` widths.

If you have content which needs to flow through, like the background of header and footer, then in that case, you can just add the wrapper, inside the element, which bears the background. For eg., if there is a `<div class="header">...</div>` has a background, which flows, you can use this way:

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="wrap">
        ...
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Let me know if you don't understand any part. :)

#### Edits in your website:

1. Replace the line 43 - 44:

   `#joel`
   `margin-top: 200px`

   with

   `#joel {`
       `margin-top: 200px;`
   `}`
2. Line number 86: Remove the `</p>`.

Let me know what is the output after these fixes.

Comment: it didnt work for me, do you have any other suggestions to use with my code in particular? (your suggestion might work with other stuff but maybe mine has something thats preventing it?)

Comment: What did you try? Can you put it and ping? Lemme check and get back to you?

Comment: ok what do you mean ping? And i tried the wrapping everything in the `<div class="wrap">` with the accompanying css

Comment: By ping I meant comment here, okay what was the output?

Comment: Where did you add? I cannot see anything you have added?

Comment: Your HTML is totally wrong. It only wraps the first navigation bar... Lemme suggest you another fix. Give me some time.

Comment: Let me know what is the output after these fixes.

Comment: the output is better as you can see in the webpage. although it is still messed up when zoomed in/out, which i really would like to fix. (The gif moves far right when you zoom out, and the elements on the right and left move farther away from each other)

Comment: You need to change your HTML badly. Do one thing... Give a width to the `body` this way: `body {width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;}`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two techniques I usually do, first is to let it reflow: http://jsfiddle.net/PALur/ and second is to maintain a fixed width and the number of columns: http://jsfiddle.net/Qg8XQ/2/ (*edit: corrected the formula to calculate width*)

Note that you need to modify the HTML, your way of dividing into columns would not work right that way.